# Why deployed serverless functions not displayed in list of lambda functions in AWS console?

Tags: node.js, serverless, aws-serverless

I deployed the serverless functions using `serverless deploy` functions to aws.

They are working fine and I can see them if I try to list the deployed function as shown below.

```sh
$ serverless deploy list functions
Serverless: Listing functions and their last 5 versions:
Serverless: -------------
Serverless: hello: $LATEST, 1, 2, 3, 4
Serverless: helloOne: $LATEST, 1
```

But I am getting no functions displayed in the list of lambda functions at AWS Console. Shouldn't they be there?

[image: AWS Console]

Comment: Do you know which region you've deployed your function to?

Comment: From console output I can see it's `region: us-east-1`

Comment: Ohh, okay I changed the region from top-right menu and I am now able to see the functions. Thanks @troy.

Answer (score 14):

It was just an issue of the region selected in the portal. My functions were deployed to `us-east-1`(you can see it in the deployment command output in terminal)

[image: deployment output]

So, as @troy commented, I changed the same from the menu at top-right, and I got the list.

[image: change region]

Answer (score 0):

make sure to overwrite the default region in serverless.yml file. This way you can make sure that the lambda function is deployed in your desired availability zone. Also, it would make your work easier when you want to use other services like databases with this function.